# cakephp button add more / less fields

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Hello I am trying to make a button that would allow me to add 2 additional fields to my form: 1 text type fields and 1 multiple choice selector (see image)

[fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgFbF.png)

I would like to be able to add these 2 fields as many times and save it in the database here is what the code of these 2 fields looks like:

```
<div class="zone_prestations">
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->label(
                        'Prestation.zone',
                        'Zone',
                        'col-sm-2 control-label'
                );
                echo $this->Form->input('Prestation.zone',
                                        array('div' =>
                                                      array(
                                                              'class' => 'col-sm-10'
                                                      ),
                                              'class' => 'form-control'
                                        ));
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php

                echo $this->Form->label(
                        'Prestation.id_contract',
                        'Préstation',
                        'col-sm-2 control-label'
                );
                echo $this->Form->input(
                        'Prestation.id_prestation',
                        array(
                                'type' => 'select',
                                'options' => $prestations,
                                'empty' => 'Selectionnez les préstations',
                                'div' => array('class' => 'col-sm-10'),
                                'class' => 'form-control search-select',
                                'multiple' => true,
                                'value' => $selected,
                                'id' => 'prestation_selector'
                        )
                );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Do you know how I could do this knowing that I have a multiple choice field. Thank you for your help

Update 20/02/21

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").select2({ width: '100%' });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxField = 10;
    var addButton = $('#add_button');
    var wrapper = $('#prestation_select');
    var x = 1;
    var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group">';
    fieldHTML += <?php echo $this->Form->label(
                    'Prestation.' + x + '.zone',
                    'Zone',
                    'col-sm-2 control-label'
            );
            echo $this->Form->input('Prestation.' + x + '.zone',
                                    array('div' =>
                                                  array(
                                                          'class' => 'col-sm-10'
                                                  ),
                                          'class' => 'form-control'
                                    ));
            ?>
    fieldHTML +='</div>';

    $(addButton).click(function () {
        if (x < maxField) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
        }

        $("select").select2({ width: '100%' });
    });

    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what your form looks like already, or this is what you want to be able to add to your form when you click a button?

Comment: this is my current form I would like to be able to add the same thing several times

Comment: You would need to add indices to your field names, like `Prestation.1.zone` instead of `Prestation.zone`, so that your controller receives an array of results instead of a single result. Then you'll need some bit of JavaScript to add copies of that but with different indices. Hope this is enough to get you started, and come back with specific questions if you run into issues with some part of implementing it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Is it possible to add indexes using php cakephp? $ this-> Form-> input (.....)?

Comment: Of course. You're doing `$this->Form->input('Prestation.zone'` now, just use `$this->Form->input('Prestation.1.zone'` or `$this->Form->input("Prestation.$index.zone"` or whatever.

Comment: @GregSchmidt thank you for your answer I followed your advice but I'm blocking on adding / removing fields (see post) I'm stuck on the exhaust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for generating `fieldHTML` is run once when your page loads, with the current version of `x`. Every time you click your add button, you'll be getting *exactly that*, always with "1" in it; it's not re-evaluated with the new `x`. Solution should be simple, just move the calculation of that HTML inside the add function.

On a separate note, don't decrement `x` when you click the remove button. If you start with field 1, then add 2 and 3 and 4, then remove 2, `x` decrementing `x` will mean that adding another field will give you a duplicate of 4. There's no need for them to be sequential, you just need distinct numbers in there.